# Stored Procedures If no record exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I got this stored procedure,

```
Create procedure [dbo].[Craping_GetFruitCrapedOrNot]
(
    @FruitID int,
    @CrateID int,
    @FruitName varchar(100)
)
AS
    SELECT Craping.Craped
    FROM Fruits 
    INNER JOIN Craping ON Fruits.ID = Craping.FruitID
    WHERE     
        (Fruits.FruitTable = @FruitName) 
        AND (Craping.FruitID = @FruitID) 
        AND (Craping.CrateID = @CrateID)
GO
```

Now I want to check if Fruits table has the fruit with provided fruit name, if there isn't any fruit then return true.

If `Fruits` and `Craping` table's inner join got no record for a `FruitID`, `CrateID` and `FruitName` then return true not false.

What we are trying to do is to only get false when a fruit is craped and logged to table.

Comment: Is it a typo the duplicate condition `Fruits.ID = Craping.FruitID`?

Comment: @RacilHilan thanks for point, it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IF EXISTS` to determine the presence of the row, and then use `CASE WHEN` to project this as the result you need, e.g.

```
Create procedure [dbo].[Craping_GetFruitCrapedOrNot]
(
    @FruitID int,
    @CrateID int,
    @FruitName varchar(100)
)
AS
  SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
  (
     SELECT     1
     FROM         Fruits 
          INNER JOIN Craping 
          ON Fruits.ID = Craping.FruitID
     WHERE     
         (Fruits.FruitTable = @FruitName) 
         AND (Craping.FruitID = @FruitID) 
         AND (Craping.CrateID = @CrateID)
  ) 
  THEN 'False'
  ELSE 'True'
  END AS FruitNotCraped
GO
```

Do you mind if I ask a question: What is a Craped Fruit? ;)

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02b94/2)

Comment: Thanks, going to test it, Craped Fruit is actually rotten fruit ;)

Comment: +1, thanks, 1 more thing, in table later on user may change "Craping.Craped" to "true" from false, so we will need value of "SELECT Craping.Craped"  if record exists, not sure how to add this

Comment: You can add additional criteria, e.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/408b2/1. Also, seems no point having both FruitName and FruitId as input params to the Proc as the ID can be looked up?